# Как вывести значение первого столбца выделенной строки в datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 2 окна, первое окно для добавления комплекта, когда пользователь заполняет его данными и доходит дело до таблицы с принтером, он нажимает на кнопку и открывается новое окно, где по моей задумке он должен выбрать двойным щелчком мышки строку, из которой хочет получить данные, после этого окно будет закрыто, а  в предыдущем в поле textbox должно будет появиться значение первого столбца, выделенной пользователем ячейки. В первом столбце - цифры, это счетчик, ключ которым связываю другие поля и он мне необходим для привязки во время добавления.  Подключал базу через ADO, работаю на С#, WPF.
Поэтому вопрос, как можно получить данные из первого столбца выделенной строки в datagrid?
Сам смог достичь лишь этого кода, который выводит содержимое столбца, по которому пользователь кликнул дважды, а это совсем не то, что нужно было мне:
C# код окна, в котором пытаюсь двойным щелчком получить и вывести данные

```
namespace YchetApparatov
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для PrinterListWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PrinterListWindow : Window
    {
        public static int SelectPrinterInt;
        public PrinterListWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DGPrinterViev.ItemsSource = NormApparatYchetEntities2.GetContext().PrinterTable.ToList();
        }

        private void DGPrinterViev_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedColumn = DGPrinterViev.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
            var selectedCell = DGPrinterViev.SelectedCells[selectedColumn];
            var cellContent = selectedCell.Column.GetCellContent(selectedCell.Item);

            if (cellContent is TextBlock)
            {
                MessageBox.Show((cellContent as TextBlock).Text);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

А это его XAML код :

```xml
<Window x:Class="YchetApparatov.PrinterListWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YchetApparatov"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PrinterListWindow" Height="720" Width="1280">
    <Grid Margin="0,97,0,34">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DGPrinterViev" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,-3,0,126"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" MouseDoubleClick="DGPrinterViev_MouseDoubleClick">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Модель принтера" Binding="{Binding ModelPrinter}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цвтеной или ЧБ" Binding="{Binding ColorOrBW}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Скорость печати в минуту" Binding="{Binding SkorostPechati}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Инвентарный номер принтера" Binding="{Binding InventarNomerPrinter}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Серийный номер принтера" Binding="{Binding SeriyNomerPrinter}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата прихода принтера" Binding="{Binding DataPrihodaPrinter}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата списания принтера" Binding="{Binding DataSpisanPrinter}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Content="Очистить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="88,-30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
        <Label Content="Фильтр" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="63"/>
        <Label Content="Поиск" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,-55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="63"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: могу добавить некоторые данные или ещё что-нибудь. 
Сейчас смотрел, нашёл решение, но оно опять же идёт не на WPF, а на windows form, а это не то

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, вот если пригодиться кому-то:

```html
    var printertable = NormApparatYchetEntities2.GetContext().PrinterTable.ToList();

            var currentItem = (PrinterTable)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
            MessageBox.Show(currentItem.IdPrinter.ToString());
```